# How to change SHA1 and SALT encrypted passwords in table

Tags: php, zend-framework, sha1, salt

I have table in mysql which contain fields id, username, password and salt:

*Example:*

**id** :       1

**username** : admin

**password** : 11ca8949f9462890f2535c9a43ac52b8c10a9342

**salt** :     8d17f0de29daed0f3b4cd38f980683d01ec50729

There are no. of records like this.

My question is : How can I change the passwords of all the users in that table.

I want to create a new password for each user. Which means I need a new SHA1 hash and salt. How can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Basically they can be changed with a simple `UPDATE` query. Could you please clarify what is the problem with changing them ?

Comment: @Teneff: You mean directly fire Update query on table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have login code then you can debug it and check it how it's working. Create appropriate script for it and update the password using following query.

```
update be_users set password=SHA1( CONCAT(  '$sha1',  '$newsalt' )), salt='your salt' where username='your username';
```

**Try this**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want everyone to have the same fixed password, and the hash consists just of the SHA1 checksum of the concatenated password and salt, this would be all it takes:

```
UPDATE users SET password = SHA1(CONCAT('newpassword', salt));
```

This keeps the original salt (which is not really a problem), but of course it's horridly insecure to give everyone the same password. If you want to generate a different password for every user, you'll need code to generate and send it to them individually, and that code might as well update each individual user's hashed password entry as well.

Alternatively, you could temporarily add a column 'newpassword', use an UPDATE command similar to the above which uses that column, then drop it. But that doesn't solve the question of how to get the new password to the users.

Comment: :And what if I have the original password of it

Comment: @Kunal: that does not matter at all if you have access to the DB. Unless you want to do something weird like change everyone's password to their previous password with some prefix or suffix. That would indeed only be possible if you knew the original plaintext password.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the original passwords in plaintext in the DB (and you certainly shouldn't!), it's not going to be a one-step process.

What you'll need to do is add another column, and give it a name like "hashtype" - this name indicates whether or not an entry has been upgraded from the old hash to the new one.

Then in your login code, after the user submits their password and it hashes correctly against the stored db hash, use the user-entered password to generate a new hash per your new method, update the hash in the db, and set hashtype to new.

Otherwise, you can do something crazy like clear all users passwords and force a password reset via email or something.

Comment: This is the best solution IMO.